# Using GATE Batch Learning PR to identify parts of emails

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, gate, information-extraction

Can the GATE Batch Leaning PR be used to reliably identify the 'composed' part of an Email i.e. just the part that was written by the sender excluding

- quoted previous conversation,
- signature
- and header (From, To,  Date).

At the moment I consider the greeting ("Dear Garry,") and the closing ("Kind Regards, John") as being part of the composed text.

I tried training with just a small hand-annotated set of emails and with the configuration shown below. As attributes I tried various features of annotation types Token, SpaceToken, Split, Date, Address and Lookup which were produced by a default ANNIE. I tried all of them together and each individually but with limited success (recall~25%, precision~50).

Can someone recommend which annotation types and features should give a good outcome? I could also use a suggestion for the other configuration parameters for example INSTANCE-TYPE.

The workings of the batch learner are still very opaque to me. For instance I couldn't find a source that explains how attributes of instances and their position are converted into a machine learning feature vector. So I wonder if the presence of a certain attribute and/or it's relative position affect the placement of the learned annotation.

Every help is appreciated. Thanks

more less interesting details:
The documentation isn't very clear on how to use the INSTANCE-TYPE option but tests show me that I can only use annotation types as attributes if they have the same range as the annotation type selected for INSTANCE-TYPE. So in order to be able to also include spaces and line breaks in the learning I slightly changed the tokenizer rules of ANNIE to create Token annotations instead of SpaceToken annotations for them. Unfortunately this didn't really improve the outcome.

batch learning config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ML-CONFIG>
        <SURROUND value="true"/>
        <FILTERING ratio="0.1" dis="near"/>
        <PARAMETER name="thresholdProbabilityEntity" value="0.2"/>
        <PARAMETER name="thresholdProbabilityBoundary" value="0.4"/>
        <PARAMETER name="thresholdProbabilityClassification" value="0.5"/>
        <multiClassification2Binary method="one-vs-others"/>
        <EVALUATION method="kfold" runs="2"/>
        <ENGINE nickname="SVM" implementationName="SVMLibSvmJava"
    options=" -c 0.7 -t 0 -m 100 -tau 0.4 "/>
        <DATASET>
            <INSTANCE-TYPE>Token</INSTANCE-TYPE>


            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>TokenCategory</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Token</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>category</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>

            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>TokenKind</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Token</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>kind</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>

            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>TokenLength</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Token</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>length</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>

            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>TokenString</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Token</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>string</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>  


            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>SpaceTokenKind</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>SpaceToken</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>kind</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>


            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>SplitKind</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Split</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>kind</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>


            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>DateKind</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Date</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>kind</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>

            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>DateRuleFinal</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Date</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>ruleFinal</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>


            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>AddressKind</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Address</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>kind</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>

            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>AddressRule</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Address</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>rule</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>

            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>AddressRuleFinal</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Address</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>ruleFinal</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>


            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>SplitKind</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Split</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>kind</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>

            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>Orthography</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Token</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>orth</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>

            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>Tokenkind</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Token</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>kind</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>

            <ATTRIBUTELIST>
                <NAME>Gaz</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Lookup</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>majorType</FEATURE>
                <RANGE from="-5" to="5"/>
            </ATTRIBUTELIST>


            <ATTRIBUTE>
                <NAME>Class</NAME>
                <SEMTYPE>NOMINAL</SEMTYPE>
                <TYPE>Mention</TYPE>
                <FEATURE>type</FEATURE>
                <POSITION>0</POSITION>
                <CLASS/>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
        </DATASET>
    </ML-CONFIG>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answers how attributes of instances and their positions are converted into machine learning feature vectors:

The code that converts a document's text into machine learning features (GATE ML attributes) can be found in `GATE/plugins/Learning/src/gate/learning/NLPFeaturesOfDoc.java` in `gatedoc2NgramFeatures(...)`

The code loops over all annotations of type INSTANCE-TYPE and produces a machine learning feature vector for each annotation using all the annotation features listed in the machine learning config xml file (config file creates `DataSetDefinition` in the code).

Prior to this process each of the features mentioned in the config file is 'multiplied' in the `DataSetDefinition` creating one feature for all elements specified by `RANGE`. If for example the element `<RANGE from="-2" to="4"/>` appears in a feature in the config then this is expanded to produce 7 features using a different `<POSITION>` element for each.